# If I've sold cigarette cards can I still get a set?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I've just meet the NPC who wants me to find sets of cigarette cards, however, I've already sold some to a fence. Will I still be able to find the cards sets or am I now out of luck since I've sold a few off?

Comment: Have you tried buying them back from the fence?

Comment: @Smeerpijp As far as I can tell, that isn't possible?

Comment: Indeed, it is not possible to buy back any sold items, from any vendor, for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can collect every single card by looting it from a specific location. There are many maps and guides available on the web which show all the locations.

Alternatively, you can buy Premium Cigarettes from the General Store for $2.50. Every pack will give you a random card. If you sold a card you looted, your only chance is to buy cigarette packs until you get the card again. Any duplicate cards can be sold to a fence for $1.00.

Note that there are 12 sets of 12 cards, for a total of 144 cards.

Comment: Sadly true - and if your honour is low the cigarettes cost a lot more! I spent $2500 to get the Coral Snake :-( . Once you have received 5 of any card if it spawns for the pack you’re buygin you get nothing so you can’t even recover $1 from the fence.